# javascript global variable not updating and ajax making same request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // i need app Id and image name from json
    var waypoint;
    var count = 0;
    var number = 0;
    var url = '{{url("/app/next/")}}/' + number;


     $(document).ready(function() {
        loadMore();       

        $(window).scroll(function() {
                $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >     
$(document).height() - 450 && 0 == count && (count = 1,loadMore())
            })
     });

     function loadMore(){
        $.getJSON(url, function(jd) {

            jd.forEach(myFunction);

            function myFunction(item, index) {

                var app = '<a href="{{url('/app/')}}/'+item.id+'"/>';

              $('#content').append(app);
               number = item.id;
              if(item.id == 1){
                count = 1;
              }
              else{
              count = 0;
              }
                 }
                return true;
           });
     }

    </script>
```

Here i am looping threw rows from last to first in database with jquery.
my php script is set to give next last element in the row and working fine if i make the request manually.
http://theviralappcreate.dev/app/next/4 will return element number 3.

whenever i scrool down it makes request at : http://theviralappcreate.dev/app/next/0    and keeps making same request, however i am updating the number variable by number = item.id;

Comment: You have only set `url` once, it doesn't change when you change `number`

Comment: no it does change it works when i make it number++; you can check it at theviralapp.in website

Comment: `number` changes but `url` won't until you set it again

Comment: or if not then what will be the solution ?

Comment: *"no it does change it works when i make it number++"* That logic makes no sense...you can clearly see it keeps making request to original url. Nothing shown will ever change the url

Comment: thanks it started working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move

```
var url = '{{url("/app/next/")}}/' + number;
```

Inside loadmore()

```
function loadMore(){
        var url = '{{url("/app/next/")}}/' + number;
        $.getJSON(url, function(jd) {
        ...
```

then as number increments each request will use updated url value